# Flutter: how to make GridView compact?

Tags: flutter, gridview

How to make the following login screen compact?

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),

      body: createGridView(),
    );
 }


Widget createGridView() {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2, shrinkWrap: true, children: const <Widget> [
        Text('Username'),
        TextField(
        ),
    
        Text('Password'),
        TextField(
        ),
      ])],
    ),
  );
}
```

On windows laptop, the Text and TextField dimensions: 632.7 x 632.7.

How to make it compact like:

```
 Username __________
 Password __________
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compact"? Based on your example it looks like what you want is a Column with 2 Row's in it, and not a GridView (which is a CustomScrollView, i.e. a grid which can be scrolled)

Comment: you might be just looking for row

Comment: @pcba-dev using gridview makes it easier for aligning the name column without hard-coding width.

Answer (score 0):

It would me more appropriate to use [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget, which uses the table layout algorithm for its children and allows aligning its children and having intrinsic widths.

`TextField` requires to have a parent widget which enforces a specific width, otherwise it will take all the horizontal space available.

```
  Widget createTable(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
        0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
        1: FlexColumnWidth(),
      },
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.baseline,
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Username'),
            TextField(...),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Password'),
            TextField(...),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```